# How can I create an overload for this method?

Tags: c++

I have a class with a method that looks like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void pushItem(std::string name, T& item)
    {
        //Adds item
    }
};
#define pushItem(...) pushItem(#__VA_ARGS__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

This allows me to write:

```
int i = 5;
fooObject.pushItem(i);
```

Instead of:

```
int i = 5;
fooObject.pushItem("i", i);
```

How can I overload the `pushItem` method so that I can pass a string manually if I want to, like this:

```
int reallyLongVariableName = 5;
fooObject.pushItem("longVar", reallyLongVariableName);
```

Comment: Why are you using a variadic macro for something that is clearly not a variadic operation?

Comment: Don't do that, unless you have a really good reason. This is violating the so-called "principle of least surprise". For example, concerning your example code, I would immediately refactor it to `fooObject.pushItem(5)` to eliminate the temporary `i` variable and it would probably break stuff.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Not sure what you mean. Why would you change it to an r-value when the method clearly requires an l-value reference? The `i` variable was just an example of an l-value that I used to demonstrate the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply rename the macro (and remove the variadic portion, as it is not needed).

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void pushItem(std::string name, T& item)
    {
        //Adds item
    }
};

#define pushValue(p) pushItem(#p, p)
```

```cpp
int i = 5;
fooObject.pushValue(i);
```

```cpp
int reallyLongVariableName = 5;
fooObject.pushItem("longVar", reallyLongVariableName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Having a macro with a non-all-caps name is a bad, bad idea.

If anything, I would do this: `#define WITH_NAME(x) #x, x`, and use it as following: `fooObject.pushItem(WITH_NAME(i));`.

Comment: If I really wanted to keep the design I have now, could I change the method name to an all-caps name(PUSH_ITEM), and then change the #define statement to what Remy Lebeau suggests in their answer below? Or would that be legal/accepted is what I'm trying to say. Again, I'm not very experienced with macros and what the correct practices with them are.

Comment: @JensB If you were my coworker, I would reject it in a core review. To be honest, there's a good (but smaller) change I'd reject what I suggested in this very answer too. *"could I change the method name to an all-caps"* I don't like it. The all-caps macro names are not for a cargo cult. Their point is to have a unique naming scheme for macros, that nothing else uses.

Comment: I see your point. The thing is that I would be calling this method for tens and tens of variables so typing out `WITH_NAME` for every call would be a bit tedious. What's bad about having a macro that's not all-caps? Wouldn't this be a special case, since I'm not trying to throw in a special value or perform a special little calculation on a value, I'm just trying to call a method that already exists, but in a slightly different manner? I trust your judgement, I'm just trying to understand it better.

Comment: @JensB Because if your macro name conflicts with anything else (like a method/variable of an unrelated class), things will break in mysterious ways. If your macro is in a .cpp file and not in a header, the things are slightly better, but still dicey. `pushItem` is a fairly common name.